# Using Individual Columns to Map Data to a Table Array

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have two columns, C1 and C2, each of which contains real valued data.  I would like to create a two-dimensional table from these columns where each row is a specific range of values in C1 (e.g. 400-500) and each column a specific range of values in C2 (e.g. 10-14).  This is easy enough by sorting C1 and C2 and determining reasonable ranges.  The key issue I is that I have a third column C3 whose values I would like to fill the table with.  In particular, I would like to be able to select C3 and have it check the associated values in C1 and C2 and use this information to place the value in the appropriate cell at the intersection of those two values of the table.  Is this something that would require VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your C3 has (C1, C2) as coordinates. Your original coordinates in C1 is a number but in the matrix it is a **non-overlapping range**, e.g., C1 can be 413 but this falls under the range 401-500 in your new matrix. It is possible to do this without VBA by using VLOOKUP for data mapping and transformation.

Of course, as the method gets more and more complex, to facilitate future reuse, amendments and readability, it is recommended to use VBA, where it is simpler to add comments and see the algorithm at work in a continuous flow.

If you want to avoid using VBA, what you could do is derive the range in which C1 falls using VLOOKUP range lookup, and combine this range and the C2 value into one cell, separated by a comma, then sort data in C3 by this new column in ascending order. Note that when using VLOOKUP range lookup, it will always give a response, as it will look for the maximum value that is equal to or less than your C1 value, so it tends not to result in #N/A; **you have to make sure that your ranges cover all possible values of C1**.

Assuming your C1 ranges are found in *Column A* and your C2 values are all found in *Row 1*, you could use VLOOKUP to populate the matrix, then handle any *#N/A* thereafter.

So we have:

*Table of C3 values*

- C1 values in Column B
- C2 values in Column C
- Combined coordinates in Column D in Sheet
- Resulting C3 values in Column E

*Table of C1 ranges*

- Minimum value of range in Column A
- Actual range in Column B

Create the table of C1 ranges

```
Min val     Range
0           0
1           1-100 
101         101-200
201         201-300
301         301-400
401         401-500
501         501-600
etc.
```

Combine the C1 and C2 coordinates into Column D. For example, this translates C1 = 413, C2 = 21 to "400-500,21",

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,TableC1Ranges!$A$2:$B$100,2)&","&C2
```

Then Sort by Column D and use VLOOKUP in the matrix of C1 and C2 values

```
=VLOOKUP($A2&","&B$1,TableC3!$D$2:$E$1000,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  My C3 does have C1,C2 coordinates but one issue is that a value from C1 will only be contained in a row of the table array.  That is, the table array row label contains a range (e.g. 400-500) while C1 contains some specific value (e.g. 431).  I think this will complicate the VLOOKUP method, won't it?

Comment: It doesn't complicate the VLOOKUP method but it does complicate the coordinates combination. You'll need to create a third table to address the possible ranges and use VLOOKUP for the coordinates combination as well.

Comment: I have amended the answer to address the range requirement.